# Spring not releasing/reusing Hibernate sessions on JBoss EAP 6

Tags: spring, hibernate, jdbc, jboss6.x

I have a Spring application using Hibernate 4.  The Hibernate config is in my application-config.xml and is shown below:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.mycompany.esb.jpa</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

In the package `com.mycompany.esb.jpa` I have the following class which all other classes in that package are subclasses of.

```
package com.mycompany.esb.jpa.dao;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class HibernateBaseDAO {

    @Autowired
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }

}
```

Here's one of those classes which I've simplified for this example.

```
package com.mycompany.esb.jpa.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.mycompany.esb.jpa.entity.ServicesEntity;

@Component("servicesDAO")
public class ServicesDAOImpl extends HibernateBaseDAO implements ServicesDAO {

    @Override
    public List<ServicesEntity> getAllServices(double daysPrevious, double hoursToShow) {
        try {

            Query query = getSession().createQuery("FROM ServicesEntity e "
                    + "WHERE e.responseTime >= (sysdate - (" + daysPrevious + " + " + hoursToShow + "/24)) "
                    + "AND e.responseTime < (sysdate - " + daysPrevious + ") "
                    + "GROUP BY e.domainName, e.serviceName, e.operationName, e.elapsedTime, e.serviceTimestamp, "
                    + "e.id, e.responseTimeAverage, e.responseTime, e.requestSizeAverage, e.responseSizeAverage, e.requestCount "
                    + "ORDER BY e.domainName, e.serviceName, e.operationName, e.serviceTimestamp");

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<ServicesEntity> services = (List<ServicesEntity>) query.list();
            return services;

        } catch (HibernateException hex) {
            hex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having is that when deployed to JBoss EAP, each time the `getAllServices()` method is called, it grabs a new connection from the JDBC pool and never releases it.  So when the container JDBC pool has a max of 5 connections, after 5 queries, subsequent queries time out because there are no available connections.  Shouldn't the connection pool be managed by the Hibernate `SessionFactory` object?  Do I need to explicitly close the connection?

Comment: and why should it? You don't have a transaction setup and next to that you do a `openSession` indicating you want to manage your own sessions.  Setup transactions and use `getCurrentSession` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As originally noted by user Orid: (he subsequently deleted his answer)

> That's because you call sessionFactory.openSession(); inside
>   getSession() in your base class and never release the session (and
>   connection) by calling close().
>
> You should should use instead sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
>   which pins a session to JTA transaction / thread depending on your
>   data source transaction resource management configuration.
>
> Also, you should annotate getAllServices with
>   @Transactional(readOnly=true) for proper transaction and connection
>   acquisition / release management.

I also had to add the `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotation to my `ServicesDAOImpl` class and enable CCM in JBoss EAP.

So my new `ServicesDAOImpl` class is below:

```
package com.mycompany.esb.jpa.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.mycompany.esb.jpa.entity.ServicesEntity;


@EnableTransactionManagement
@Component("servicesDAO")
public class ServicesDAOImpl extends HibernateBaseDAO implements ServicesDAO {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    @Override
    public List<ServicesEntity> getAllServices(double daysPrevious, double hoursToShow) {
        Query query = getSession().createQuery("FROM ServicesEntity e "
                + "WHERE e.responseTime >= (sysdate - (" + daysPrevious + " + " + hoursToShow + "/24)) "
                + "AND e.responseTime < (sysdate - " + daysPrevious + ") "
                + "GROUP BY e.domainName, e.serviceName, e.operationName, e.elapsedTime, e.serviceTimestamp, "
                + "e.id, e.responseTimeAverage, e.responseTime, e.requestSizeAverage, e.responseSizeAverage, e.requestCount "
                + "ORDER BY e.domainName, e.serviceName, e.operationName, e.serviceTimestamp");
        try {
            return (List<ServicesEntity>) query.list();
        } catch (HibernateException hex) {
            hex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

... and my new `HibernateBaseDAO` class is below:

```
package com.mycompany.esb.jpa.dao;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public abstract class HibernateBaseDAO {

    @Autowired
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

}
```